# Nested abbrivations: PEAP-MS-CHAP-v2

Tags: abbreviations

What is the proper abbreviation of `Protected Extensible Authentication Protocol Microsoft Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol version 2`?

Is it `PEAP MS-CHAP v2` or `PEAP-MS-CHAP-v2` or another one?

Common abbreviations of its components are:

- `Extensible Authentication Protocol` is abbreviated as `EAP`.
- `Protected Extensible Authentication Protocol` is abbreviated as `EAP` or `Protected EAP`.
- `Microsoft Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol version` is abbreviated as `MS-CHAP v2` or `MS-CHAP-v2`.

**Meaning**: The term refers to a framework of protocols (EAP) that apply a protocol that itself is not mentioned by name (TLS), but indicated by speaking of `Protected`. In the second part, the vendor/developer (Microsoft/MS) is mentioned as well as a protocol that is applied in the context of EAP: The second version of Microsoft's CHAP.

**Sources**: The documentation of the protocol and its components by the vendor is inconclusive.

Comment: There is no "correct" answer to this from an English perspective. Or, rather, the correct answer from an English perspective is "whatever is most commonly used by authorities on the matter". English is indifferent otherwise. So whatever MS says or uses in its documentation or whatever is most common among professional practitioners in the field is what is "right".

Comment: If I search for [PEAP MS-CHAP v2](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PEAP+MS-CHAP+v2), not only does Google suggest another variation, but almost every result has its own version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Microsoft is the authority on this then:

> PEAP-MS-CHAP v2-based Authenticated Wireless Access Design

That's what I'd have been going for myself as well. Be consistent. Either all dashes, or no dashes.

Note there is no dash before the "v2".

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd348500(v=ws.10).aspx

Oxford Dictionary has a guide on how to use it with compound words.
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/hyphen

Comment: I'd prefer `PEAP-MS-CHAPv2-based`... as spaces in hyphenated items lead to confusion and wierd line-breaking.  The change of case is traditionally adequate as a word boundary n many computing fields.

Comment: On Windows Server 2008 R2, in the Routing and Remote Access MMC snap-in, it's written MS-CHAP v2. In the Network Policy Server MMC snap-in, it's written MS-CHAP-v2. That's one example for the inconsistency, not in a random document, but production software.